# Localizable assets in Android

Tags: android, localization, internationalization

I just found a [nice tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919800/how-to-embed-html-code-in-android-app) that will help me implement an easy user guide system in my application, as I will be able to draw it with any plain old HTML editor.

My question is simple: since all `res`ources are localizable, I can easily translate my application into new languages. What about `assets`? Is there an automatic localization mechanism? I don't think so.

How do I retrieve system locale in order to construct a localized URL when loading the help page's HTML file? Is there some call to retrieve display size/density the same as coded in the resources world (ie. `public String getDensity()` returns "xhdpi", "ldpi"...)?

Danke ;-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you really need to check current system locale, one simple way to do it is to add an identifier string in your strings.xml files.

For example, in values/strings.xml, add:

```
<string name="lang">en</string>
```

in values-es/strings.xml, add:

```
<string name="lang">es</string>
```

in values-fr/strings.xml, add:

```
<string name="lang">fr</string>
```

and so on. Then you'll be able to check current language programmatically with something like this (to be improved of course, just as an example):

```
if( "es".equals( getString(R.string.lang) ) ) {
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: If you want to get the selected language of your device, this might help you: Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();

Answer (score 3):

It is an old question, but just in case someone is doing this. I don't think you need an extra language string as suggested above:

```
<string name="lang">fr</string>
```

Simply add the assets URL string and translate it:

```
<string name="content_location">file:///android_asset/en/index.html</string>
```

in values-fr/strings.xml, add:

```
<string name="content_location">file:///android_asset/fr/index.html</string>
```

and then in the code access it as:

```
String URL = getResources().getString(R.string.content_location);
```

and this should display the URL based on the local since you defined it into the specific localized string files.

Comment: hi.. so we need to create a folder called as en and fr?

Answer (score 1):

See reference to android.view.Display class ([reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html)) and java.util.Locale class ([reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html))

Answer (score 1):

Look the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5427995/715269), especially notice the comment.