# How to display a lot of text lines

Tags: android, text, textview

I am working on an Android app for tourists where I show a list of all rooms in my city for accomodation. I have approximately 500 lines of text, about 5 lines for each room (adress, phone number, contact person, email adress and stars rating). I want to put all that text in one activity so you can scroll and read that text.

Should I use `TextView` or something else? Should I save that whole text in res/strings.xml?

Comment: Why use a single activity? I would prefer to go with Tabs and Fragments! Every fragment could be a room or a set of rooms (cheap, expensive, luxurious) and so on...

Comment: Agreed with Pavios, but at least use a ListView. Single scrollable TextView with that much text - yeuch!

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with using `TextViews`just do not forgot about using `ScrollView` for your layout so you can scroll your TextViews.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a WebView and display the text in HTML format.

I did it for big documents and used the assets folder to store and load the document.

Internationalization can be kept using following technique:

[What's the best practice to deploy localized documents in Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15655980/whats-the-best-practice-to-deploy-localized-documents-in-android-app)